# Content-security-policy with a hash for an event handler does not work on iOS Safari

Tags: content-security-policy

Is there a way to make iOS Safari respect 'unsafe-hashes' in a content-security-policy for inline event handlers? Is there another workaround besides using 'unsafe-inline'?

iOS Safari 14.3 reports a violation of the CSP for "script-src" while Firefox and Chrome on desktop and android work as expected.

Replacing inline event handlers does not look possible at this moment, because the event handlers are generated by JSF/Mojarra.

Here is the test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xml:lang="en"
    lang="en"
>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <!-- works in Firefox on Desktop, Chrome on Desktop, Firefox on Android, Chrome on Android -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-9tftRELs2TcRhB+bln6nFx6j6k3J4ESyFzUOJgDFjew=' 'report-sample'; report-uri /csp-report"></meta>
        <!-- works in Firefox on Desktop, Firefox on Android -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Polic1" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'                                 'sha256-9tftRELs2TcRhB+bln6nFx6j6k3J4ESyFzUOJgDFjew=' 'report-sample'; report-uri /csp-report"></meta>
        <!-- works in Firefox on Desktop, Chrome on Desktop, Firefox on Android, Chrome on Android -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Polic2" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'                 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-9tftRELs2TcRhB+bln6nFx6j6k3J4ESyFzUOJgDFjew=' 'report-sample'; report-uri /csp-report"></meta>
        <!-- works in Firefox on Desktop, Chrome on Desktop, Firefox on Android, Chrome on Android, iOS Safari -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Polic3" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'                                                                       'report-sample'; report-uri /csp-report"></meta>
    </head>

    <body>

        <a href="#" onclick="alert('test'); return false">Test</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've gathered so far myself on the subject.

In CSP level 2 (which is the latest spec) you can't, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/, section 7.15:

*Whenever the user agent would execute an inline script from an inline event handler, instead the user agent MUST NOT execute script, and MUST report a violation.*

That said, a CSP3-compliant browser would in theory let you use the "unsafe-hashes" directive, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#changes-from-level-2, specifically, point 8:

*The 'unsafe-hashes' source expression will now allow event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigation targets to match hashes.*

See this list for compatible browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=unsafe-hashes

As a confirmation, I tried this out on Chrome 92 with this simple HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-WOdSzz11/3cpqOdrm89LBL2UPwEU9EhbDtMy2OciEhs=';">
  <button onclick="alert('foo');">click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and it worked, showing the alert when I clicked the button.

So, I think it's normal that it doesn't work on Safari, given that it's listed as a non-compliant browser. The weird thing is that it works from Firefox 91, which is also listed as non-compliant. Maybe the information on caniuse.com is just incomplete.

I guess that until CSP level 3 becomes widely supported, we just have to comply with CSP 2, which means putting our scripts in separate JS files and attaching handlers from there. On the other hand, doing this also happens to be more secure (hence the “unsafe” in the new directive).

Comment: Accepting the answer unless someone has a way to use a resanable CSP policy on iOS Safari with inline event handlers.